# Select2 enable edit/typing on preset tags element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 input with precompiled values.
I have set `tags: true` to add possibility to add new tags.

But in some cases i need to change little parts of an existing already preset tag.

I can type all manually but i'd prefer to select one preset tag and continue edit it.

In my fiddle example i'd like to "reuse" the second option: `This is a string long i want to edit` selecting it and modify to `This is a string long i want to edit with this new end` 
How can I re-enable editing it, maybe putting the selected preset option inside: `select2-search__field` ?

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1s06xoq4/1/